# Solving CORS using a firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

As you know we can't fetch a `url` on a client side due to `CORS`.
I am trying to create a function, that will fetch the file for me with the right headers as an agent, and will return it to the client.

So, on `Firebase Function` :

```
exports.urlToBlob = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {

    var url = "https://..."; //request.query.url;
      fetch (
          url,
          {
             method: 'GET',
             headers: { 'Accept': '*/*' }
          }
       )
       .then ((res) => {console.log(res);return res;})

       .catch((err) => response.status(400).send(err))
   });
});
```

I can see that it will access the url and get a respond on shell **simulator**, but not on browser, which will return nothing.

The client suppose to access it with :

```
  var url = "https://us-central1-myproject-6xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/urlToBlob";
        $.get(
        url,
        {url :imgurl, platform : 'xxx'},
        function(data) {
              console.log(data);
        }
       );
```

I know i am doing it wrong, but i have to find a way to use the function to solve the `CORS`.

Answer (score 1):

Have  you tried use [cors lib from nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
You can make a configuration for cors to allow cors in your instance.
First install cors lib:

```
npm install cors --save
```

After that you can configure cors in you main module application.
As an example:

```
const cors = require('cors')
//cors config
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://example.com'] //<-- Here you put the domain you want to call your api
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
  optionsSuccessStatus:200,
  credentials: true
}))
```

In your  code:

```
.then ((res) => {console.log(res);return res;})
```

You should change to:

```
 .then ((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    //return res;
    response.status(200).send(res);
 })
```

Comment: HEY, thanks, i wrote that the CORS works on the server, but i can't pass the res to client for some reason. It is empty.

Comment: thanks, so if i use your edited code, and access this function on the browser, i will see: {"size":0,"timeout":0}

Comment: You will see what you print in `console.log(res)`, maybe if you need this information you can use `console.log(res.body)`.

Comment: thanks, did you see how i access it on the client side with $.get ? please look at my question, you can see there that i print console.log(data); , which show an empty object

Comment: Yes, i see. But don't know what you are using for do the request in client side.